# How to write JPA join?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two tables Product and Price. Product can have multiple prices depending upon time period.

**Product Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

List<Price> price;

}
```

**Price Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Price {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

LocalDate timePeroid;

Double price;

@ManyToOne()
Product product;
}
```

I want Products Entities where time period in 3 dynamic dates.But if time period does not exist then also i should have product entity but the list price should contain three null values.How can i write query for this in JPA.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JpaRepository or EntityManagerFactory for querying data in JPA.

**1. JpaRepository**

You can create repository for your product entity like following.

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

}
```

Then after dependency injection of your repository.

```
 @Resource
 ProductRepository productRepository;
```

You can use this repository to get required product e-g.

```
 Product product = productRepository.findById(id);
```

**2. EntityManagerFactory**

After dependency injection of EntityManagerFactory

```
 @Resource
 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

you can retrieve data like.

```
 EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
 Product product =  entityManager.find(Product.class, id)
```

In both of the above cases resultant product will contain its list of prices if they are persisted in database otherwise list will be empty.

For joining with special conditions you can check out the way of writing your custom queries in both entity manager factory and Jpa repository, following links might be helpful to you.

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-three-custom-queries-with-query-methods/

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting the price objects as a list within the product. I agree that if you want a special case where you want only one price, you can write a query. The other way is to write a ‘getCurrentPrice(Date d) method. (a second version without a parameter would use ‘today’ as the date). You compare the date to the date range of each price and return the correct one from the list. Regardless of how many prices are in the list, this would probably be what you would want to call in your code.